# Sequelize update nested property in JSONB

Tags: sequelize.js, jsonb

I am looking for a way to update only a nested key/value inside `jsonb` column.
here is the `User` model:

```
const User= sequelize.define('User', {
    id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    name:DataTypes.STRING,
    // other fields
    data: DataTypes.JSONB
});
```

current `data` column value:

```
{
 'email':{'verified':false,'token':'random token'},
 'phone:{'verified':true}
}
```

I want to update `email.verified` property to `true` using a **single** `update` query.

I tried following codes:

```
models.User.update({'data.email.verified':true},
       {where:{id:1}}).then()...

models.User.update({data:{email:{verified:true}}},
       {where:{id:1}}).then()...
```

the updated column would be:

```
{
 'email':{'verified':true},
}
```

I also tried this:

```
models.User.findById(1).then(user => {
    user.set('data.email.verified', true);
    user.save().then()...
});
```

this works but i don't want to execute two query (select and then update) for only updating a field.

Is it possible to do this using `sequelize` with a single update query?

Answer (score 16):

model.**yourJsonB**.userName

```
model.yourJsonB.userName = "Lisa" // traditional prop change
model.changed("yourJsonB", true)   // << forces sequelize to understand this json has been updated
await model.save()
```

I found this here:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html

Comment: works but you have to add await on save like await model.save() . thx

Comment: works perfectly, great!

Comment: OMG! Thank you. So irritating that we have to flag the JSONB field as changed manually.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can update a nested json property with sequelize using a single update query but you have to use the raw queries.

```
sequelize.query(`UPDATE users SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{email,verified}', 'true', true) WHERE id = 1`);
```